# Problema al cargar javascript de mailchimp en wordpress

Tags: javascript

Estoy intentando cargar este javascript de mailchimp:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//downloads.mailchimp.com/js/signup-forms/popup/embed.js" data-dojo-config="usePlainJson: true, isDebug: false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">require(["mojo/signup-forms/Loader"], function(L) { L.start({"baseUrl":"mc.us7.list-manage.com","uuid":"ae36fe34cde0ee5ef6fef86df","lid":"ddfbfe8c03"}) })</script>
```

Pero cada vez que lo cargo en la página principal de mi sitio al final el slider que tengo en la cabecera del sitio, desaparece automáticamente. ¿Alguien sabe si hay alguna incompatibilidad entre revolution slider y el meter código en el footer de una pagina en wordpress? ¿Acaso he redactado mal el javascript?

A ver si podéis echarme una mano, porque ya le he dado mil vueltas y no doy con la solución.

Edito:

Sin javascript: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Con javascript instalado: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: puedes poner una imagen de cómo debiera verse el slider y cómo se ve cuando desaparece? A lo mejor el script que cargas cambia algún estilo

Comment: Espero que con la imagen te hagas una idea. Si quieres visitar la pagina es cherubina.com